# How do I build Ubuntu 20.10 kernel and modules for Raspberry PI (aarch64)?

Tags: server, 20.04, kernel, raspberrypi, 20.10

What I'm looking for is **up to date instructions** on how to install and build the Ubuntu 20.10 5.8.0-1015-raspi kernel and module?.   *Please note I don not want to compile the Raspberry PI OS kernel or modules.*

Or if thats not possible to cross compile it from whatever environment it can be built on?

I'm attempted to build the Ubuntu 20.10 kernel and modules for aarch64 using instructions I've found using web searches (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel).  The reason being is there are modules missing from the ubuntu build that are in the generic ARM64 build that I would like to use in the RASPI distribution.

Its been a number of decades since I built a kernel and thus far I've not managed to successfully compile one..

```
root@ys:/usr/src/linux-source-5.8.0/linux-raspi-5.8.0# make
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CALL    scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/vc04_services/bcm2835-camera/bcm2835-camera.o
In file included from ./include/media/v4l2-subdev.h:15,
                 from ./include/media/v4l2-device.h:13,
                 from drivers/staging/vc04_services/bcm2835-camera/bcm2835-camera.c:20:
drivers/staging/vc04_services/bcm2835-camera/bcm2835-camera.c: In function ‘buffer_cb’:
drivers/staging/vc04_services/bcm2835-camera/bcm2835-camera.c:333:35: error: ‘struct mmal_buffer’ has no member named ‘length’
  333 |    __func__, status, buf, mmal_buf->length, mmal_buf->mmal_flags,
```

Comment: https://wiki.arm-image-builder.xyz/ ... useful?

Comment: https://github.com/arter97/exfat-linux/issues/34

Comment: Thanks for the responses after exploring each of them neither of them get me any further forward.  :-(